# Error Creating new Flutter App with AndrodX

Tags: flutter, androidx

I'm trying to create a Flutter app with Android-X
following this this [INFORMATION](https://www.josh.app/blog/flutter-with-androidx/),

the date is quite recent,
so I'm assuming they are up to date.

The problem is when I run on flutter console

> flutter create -a kotlin -i swift --androidx my-app-name

I get this error:

> Could not find an option named "androidx".

(running: flutter create blablabla everything works fine)

[edit: this is my flutter doctor]

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
> Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.17763.557], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 28.0.3) [√] Android Studio (version 3.3) [√] VS Code (version
> 1.35.1) [√] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

Did I miss something?

Comment: what is your version of Flutter?
Look https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/31028. The AndroidX support has been merged 2 weeks ago. So it's not in a stable release, which is available on Flutter website: v1.5.4-hotfix.2-stable. So you probably need to install the latest build: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases, e.g. 1.7.3

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.557], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

Comment: yes, that's what i told you about. This new feature won't work in v1.5.4-hotfix.2

Comment: @bdshadow so, how am I supposed to create it?

Comment: read my first comment once again: install latest flutter minor release, e.g. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases/tag/v1.7.4